# how to make a verification while loop in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd want to ask you a question concerning a while loop. I've looked eve

```
#!/bin/bash
# Username and password loop;do
 
       
        fi
done
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the beginning of your loop. Also, it's not clear where you're setting values for `$Admin` and `$Secret`.

Comment: @Steven : There is no loop in your code. Please post the **complete** code. I also suggest to paste your program into [shellcheck](shellcheck.net), before asking here such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but it seems that you're missing `while true; do` and the `break` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

Admin="the_admin_user"
Secret="the_secret_password"

while true; do
    read -p "Please Enter Username  : " Username
    if [[ "$Username" = "$Admin" ]]
    then
        echo "Username is Correct"
        break
    else
        echo "Username is Wrong"
    fi
done

while true; do
    read -p "Please Enter Password  : " Password1
    read -p "Enter Password Again   : " Password2

    if [[ "$Password1" != "$Password2" ]]
    then
        echo "Passwords don't match! Try again."
    elif [[ "$Password1" = "$Secret" ]]
    then
        echo "Password is Correct"
        break
    else
        echo "Password is Wrong"
    fi
done

echo "Success!"
```